# Some games display wrong sprites

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, gpu

A strange graphics glitch renders two games unplayable on a Windows 7 laptop with GeForce GT 720M (and also an Intel integrated GPU):

[image: Example 1 (game Cook, Serve, Delicious!)]

[image: Example 2 (game VA-11 HALL-A)]

Both games have been showing these symptoms since the moment of installation. The games are made using different engines and use hardware rendering (if I am not mistaken).

Other games and graphical applications (both 2d and 3d, e.g. Oxenfree and Blender) work fine.

This looks like a GPU memory issue to me (the game displays wrong spritesheets with wrong sizes), but I have no idea what might be causing it. Is reinstalling GPU driver a reasonable first step? What else should I do to diagnose and fix the issue?

**UPDATE:** I have installed [the latest GeForce driver](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/113446) for this video card and rebooted the PC. The problem remains, nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: Reinstalling latest GPU is nearly always a reasonable first step and improves your question's likelihood of being answered as we can see you've tried things already.

Comment: @music2myear Okay, I will try it. It's just that reinstalling the driver often magically fixes graphics issues on many PCs and we do not get to know the exact cause of the issue (at least whether it was a driver bug or not).